# Why is the GetObject Method Failing?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a VSTO app built in Visual Studio that runs this block of code:

```
using MSP = Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
using VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic;

if (IsMSProjectIsOpen())
{
     pApp = (MSP.Application)VB.Interaction.GetObject(Class: "MSProject.Application");
}
else
{
     pApp = CreateMSProjectApp();
}
```

This has always worked but it was failing on one of my user's computers today for some reason.

I ran a test on that computer using the Microsoft Project VBA editor to try to set the [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Project.Application) object using the [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function) method:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim app As MSProject.Application
    
    Set app = GetObject(Class:="MSProject.Application")

End Sub
```

Normally the app object would get set just fine and look like this in the locals window:
[image]

for some reason, the computer I'm testing on using the exact same code sets the app object so it's not null but when you expand the node in the locals window it shows **No Variables**:

[image: No Variables]

And when you try to access any of it's properties or methods it throws an error:

[image: Error message]

What's going on here?

Comment: If you're running this in Project why not use `Set app = Application`?  Is it possible you have a hidden instance of Project running in the background?

Comment: What is your end goal of using the `GetObject` method in VBA? Do you automate if from another Office application?

Comment: And why do you need to connect to the MSProject running instance instead of just creating a new one?

Comment: As stated in the above comments, there are some not clarified issues: 1. Do you need setting the respective object **through automation of another application** (Office apps, Corel DRAW etc.)? If so, does `ms-project` work as it should if you manually **open it and try using VBA in the respective instance**? It may be corrupted. 2. If the respective code works in Project VBA, **why do you need that way of setting**? It theoretically should return the open session, the same as `Set app = Application`. 3. What do you intend doing with existing instance? Is there something already open, to check?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev and everyone else - yes I am trying to use the `GetObject` method in a C# written application referencing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject` method. I just used the code snippet above for simplicity's sake.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are seeing?

Comment: Does the `new` operator work correctly instead of `GetObject`?

Comment: @FaneDuru I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Forget about trying to prove the application property missing... Try anything to see if the object really have the necessary properties and it is not corrupted. For instance, does `Debug.Print app.Caption` return anything? If not, it means that the installation is corrupted and you need to reinstall it. What do you see if try expanding Modulel1 from Locals window?

Answer (score 1):

> call was rejected by callee

The Office message pump retrieves the message and dispatches it to a hidden OLE window where the call is un-marshalled and executed. However, before executing the call, COM first checks with Office to ensure that it is actually able to handle the call. In some cases, the call could result in an undesirable case of reentrancy (such as when Office is in a modal state or it is in the middle of a long operation like a conversion). In those cases, Office can tell COM that it is too busy to handle the call, in which case `RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED` is returned to the caller. In your case, the failure is being converted by COM interop to an exception.

To overcome this, Microsoft recommends to disable the COM Add-ins.

> yes I am trying to use the GetObject method in a C# written application referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject method.

Note, when two applications are run under different security contexts in Windows you will not be able to connect to the running instance. Your choice is to create a new instance under the same security context and automate it then.